# Many-to-one in hibernate join

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, join, criteria

I want to make join between Entry entity and Project entity. My goal is to search entries by assigned project id. I enter project id and i want to get all entries with this project assigned.

This is my method in DAO class

```
@Override
    public PageWrapper<Entry> getListOfEntries(EntrySC sc) {
        public PageWrapper<Entry> getListOfEntries(EntrySC sc) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Entry> cq = cb.createQuery(Entry.class);
    Root<Entry> entry = cq.from(Entry.class);
    //Join<Entry,Project> join = cq.from(Entry.class).join(Entry_.project);

    cq.select(entry);

    PageWrapper<Entry> results = new PageWrapper<>();
    results.setResults(em.createQuery(cq).getResultList());
    results.setRows(em.createQuery(cq).getResultList().size());

    return results;
    }
```

And this is my Entry entity and Project entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Entry")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="Entry.findAll", query="SELECT e FROM Entry e ORDER BY e.date DESC"),
    @NamedQuery(name="Entry.findByID", query="SELECT e FROM Entry e WHERE e.id = :entryID"),
    @NamedQuery(name="Entry.findByUserID", query="SELECT e FROM Entry e WHERE e.user.id = :userID ORDER BY e.date DESC"),
    @NamedQuery(name="Entry.findByProjectID", query="SELECT e FROM Entry e WHERE e.project.id = :projectID")
})
public class Entry extends BaseEntityAudit {


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PROJECT_ID", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Project project;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "COMMENT", nullable = true)
    private String comment;

    @Column(name = "HOURS", nullable = false)
    private BigDecimal hours;

    @Column(name = "DATE", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date date;


    public Entry(){}

    //setters and getters

}

@Entity
@Table(name="Project")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="Project.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM Project p"),
    @NamedQuery(name="Project.findByID", query="SELECT p FROM Project p WHERE p.id = :projectID")
})
public class Project extends BaseEntityAudit {

    @Column(name="NAME", nullable=false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name="START_DATE", nullable=false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date startDate;

    @Column(name="DUE_DATE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dueDate;

    @Column(name="COMMENT", nullable=true)
    private String comment;


    public Project(){

    }

    //setters and getters
}
```

The project class dont know about entries. Maybe this is the problem?

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Edit:

I created join base on documentation. But its not clear to me. Because if i uncomment this i will get null pointer exception. I also created metamodel class

```
@StaticMetamodel(Entry.class)
public class Entry_ {

    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Entry,Project> project;

    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Entry,User> user;

    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Entry, String> comment;

    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Entry,BigDecimal> hours;

    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Entry,Date> date;

}
```

Comment: Only the fact that project class does not have a dependency to entries cannot be a problem. But something is probably wrong in your query since you don't even use the argument `sc` in `getListOfEntries`

Comment: yes im not using it yet, because now my goal is to search only entries with project id lets say 1. While i reach this goal i will be using sc

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you already defined the `NamedQuery` annotations, I suppose you intended to use them when querying. [Here](https://www.journaldev.com/3451/hibernate-named-query-example-namedquery) you can find the examples you need. Otherwise if you prefer to construct the query with `CriteriaQuery` you can adopt [these](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gjivi/index.html) examples.

Comment: I used them but now i want to change it to the criteria api

Comment: its not clear for me i have created join, but then i got null pointer exceptions